# Cast function argument as a character string?

Tags: r

Super quick question...

How do you take a some particular function's (user-defined) argument and cast it as a character-string?

If for a simple example,

```
foo <- function(x) { ... }
```

I want to simply return x's object name. So,

```
foo(testing123)
```

returns `"testing123"` (and testing123 could just be some random numeric vector)

Apologies if this question has been asked before--searched, but couldn't find it! Thanks!!

Answer (score 43, accepted):

```
foo <- function(x) deparse(substitute(x))
```

Answer (score 20):

Meta-answer: if you know R does something and you want to do it, check the source. For example, you may have spotted that `plot(foo)` sticks 'foo' in the `ylab`, so plot can do it. How? Start by looking at the code:

```
> plot
function (x, y, ...) 
{
    if (is.function(x) && is.null(attr(x, "class"))) {
        if (missing(y)) 
            y <- NULL
        hasylab <- function(...) !all(is.na(pmatch(names(list(...)), 
            "ylab")))
        if (hasylab(...)) 
            plot.function(x, y, ...)
        else plot.function(x, y, ylab = paste(deparse(substitute(x)), 
            "(x)"), ...)
    }
    else UseMethod("plot")
}
```

And there's some `deparse(substitute(x))` magic.

Comment: Not sure if it really matters, as the answer itself is great, but `plot` doesn't look like this anymore

Answer (score 2):

Whoops, apparently I didn't search hard enough...

```
foo <- function(x) {return(as.character(substitute(x)))}
```

Well that's easy...

Comment: `deparse(substitute(x))` would be the usual way of doing this, as per JD's answer. Compare your version with JD's on this `foo(testing * bar)` to see why.