# How to get names of dot-dot-dot arguments in R

Tags: r, ellipsis

How obtaining a characters vector containing the name of the dot-dot-dot arguments passed to a function  e.g.:

```
test<-function(x,y,...)
{
    varnames=deparseName(substitute(list(...)))
    # deparseName does not exist, this is what I want !
    # so that I could *for example* call:

    for(elt in varnames)
       {print(varnames);}
}

v1=11
v2=10
test(12,12,v1,v2)

## would print 
#v1
#v2
```

Comment: check out `match.call`

Comment: just `print(list(...))` inside the function should do. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/5213372/4137985

Comment: @Cath. print(list(...)) does not give the expected output. It prints the content of variables.

Comment: This [link](https://www.r-bloggers.com/r-three-dots-ellipsis/) might be interesting for you

Comment: I guess `print(names(list(...)))` will do what you want

Comment: To be clear, despite the title this question is *not* asking for argument names, but names passed as arguments, e.g. for `y` but not `x` in `f(x = 10, y)`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use `deparse` and `substitute` to get what you want (see also [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4108577/4137985)):

```
test<-function(x, y, ...)
{
    varnames=lapply(substitute(list(...))[-1], deparse)
    lapply(varnames, print)
    return(invisible())
}

test(12,12,v1,v2)
#[1] "v1"
#[1] "v2"
```

Answer (score 15):

Try this:

```
test<-function(x,y,...)
{
  mc <- match.call(expand.dots = FALSE)
  mc$...
}

v1=11
v2=10
test(12,12,v1,v2)
[[1]]
v1

[[2]]
v2
```

Answer (score 6):

To extend the other answers a bit, if you *just* want the parameters passed to `...` that are names, you can use `is.name` to subset the unevaluated dots before deparsing them to strings:

```r
v1 <- 12
v2 <- 47
v3 <- "foo"

test <- function(x, y, ...){
    dots <- match.call(expand.dots = FALSE)$...
    dots <- dots[sapply(dots, is.name)]
    sapply(dots, deparse)
}

test(2, y = v1, z = v2, 1, v3)
#>    z      
#> "v2" "v3"
```

Answer (score 3):

So, here's how `match.call` works :

- `match.call()[[1]]` returns the name of the function

Then all the args are passed, so match.call()[[2]] and match.call()[[3]] return the 1 and 2nd param, with the value if there is no name (as here) :

```
test<-function(x,y,...) {
  list(
    match.call()[[1]],
    match.call()[[2]], 
    match.call()[[3]],
    match.call()[[4]],
    match.call()[[5]]
    )
}

v1=11
v2=10
test(12,12,v1,v2)
[[1]]
test

[[2]]
[1] 12

[[3]]
[1] 12

[[4]]
v1

[[5]]
v2
```

So if you need, here, the dots, you can do :

```
test<-function(x,y,...) {
  mc <- match.call()
  res <- c()
  for (i in 4:length(mc)){
    res <- c(res, mc[[i]])
  }
  res
}
```