# R select column of data frame by name

Tags: r, dataframe

I am aware of selecting a column of data frame using `data$column`. My question - Is there a way to do that dynamically where I create a function and pass data, `columnName` as parameter and get the result back

```
fnGetColumnData (data, columnName) {
   data$columnName
}
```

above does not work when encapsulating the code in a function. However if I write `data$"columnName"` then it works. Is there a way to encapsulate this?

Comment: Consider the answers to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4108577/6574038) question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
select_col<-function(df,colname){
 colname<-deparse(substitute(colname))
  df[colname]
}
select_col(iris,Species)
```

Answer (score 1):

With `dplyr` and `rlang`:

```
library(dplyr)
library(rlang)

fnGetColumnData = function(data, columnName){
  colname_quo = enquo(columnName)
  pull(data, !!colname_quo)
}
```

**Output:**

```
> fnGetColumnData(mtcars, "cyl")
 [1] 6 6 4 6 8 6 8 4 4 6 6 8 8 8 8 8 8 4 4 4 4 8 8 8 8 4 4 4 8 6 8 4

> fnGetColumnData(mtcars, cyl)
 [1] 6 6 4 6 8 6 8 4 4 6 6 8 8 8 8 8 8 4 4 4 4 8 8 8 8 4 4 4 8 6 8 4
```